# Constant expressions are not allowed in the ORDER BY clause - how else should I write a case?

Tags: sql-server

Why not? What is a good replacement for this functionality which was removed in newer versions of SQL server?

I use the following pattern all over the place:

```
select * from ContactReport 
order by 
case ContactDate when null then 'a' else 'b' end, ContactMethod
```

I could change it to this, but it would be slower:

```
select * from ContactReport 
order by 
case ContactDate when null then 'a'+ContactMethod else 'b'+ContactMethod end
```

In some instances I have very large tables and this would be a problem. I could add some dummy columns eg Dummy1,Dummy2,Dummy3 with value 1 to every table where I need this just so I can order by it...

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have misunderstood what the error is telling you. It is perfectly fine to have constants in branches of `CASE` statements - just the whole expression is not allowed to resolve to a constant.

```
case ContactDate when null then 'a' else 'b' end
```

is incorrect. With ANSI defaults enabled it will always evaluate to "b" as nothing is equal to null. SQL Server can tell this at compile time and constant fold it to `b`. It is meaningless to order by a value that is the same in all rows - hence the error.

This error is not new, it occurs at least as far back as 2008 - it is a good thing because otherwise you would just silently get the wrong results without rows with `NULL` dates ordered first as desired.

Your expression does work with `ANSI_NULLS` off (and compiles OK in the `ORDER BY` clause) but I don't recommend using that.

Use the following expression instead.

```
case when ContactDate is null then 'a' else 'b' end
```

Or, this can be shortened to

```
IIF(ContactDate is null, 'a', 'b')
```

Comment: Nice one! Pleased that was just this particular case because it was actually a mistake in the syntax. It was previously set to sql2000 compatibility level on a sql2008 server, and the upgrade to sql2019 dragged up the compatibility level by several notches (not sure why they can't keep full backwards compatibility - seems rather arbitrary). But in this case a good thing since it caught a mistake which was previously not noticed!

Comment: The `IIF(ContactDate is null, 'a', 'b')` syntax is nice, makes the statement more readable and prevents getting syntax errors like mine.